# Pagination links in original revision history of moved example broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, revision-history, move-examples

The pagination links in the original revision history of a moved example are pointing to a 404 status returning URL.

See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/revisions/194?exampleId=730

The links of the pagination are using the id of the destination topic instead of the original topic (destination topic id is 6695):

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/revisions/6695?exampleid=730&page=2

instead of the correct (original topic id is 194):

https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/revisions/194?exampleid=730&page=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We relied on the Example to provide the revisions link there, which was a bad move. Starting with the next build, we'll explicitly specify the ID of the topic whose revisions are currently being viewed.

Thanks for the report!